# Asterisk, how to log holdtime announce time?

Tags: asterisk

I have a somekind specific problem. Asterisk can announce estimated waiting time for clients in queue, and this is fine except i need to log that time it going to announce. In other words, each time if asterisk going to say to client that client is going to wait in line another %TIME% minutes, i need to have that %TIME% logged near the call id.

Is there any way to do so? Maybe there is some log setting i missed out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemented way. But seams like easy add event in app_queue.c. Should not take more then 1-2hours for anyone with c/c++ experience.